# communicate data between two different components in angular2

Tags: angular, components

I have two different individual components and i want to share any data between both means any variable data is updated in one component then it should be updated in the view of other component automatically.
Need Help.

Answer (score 1):

Create an injectable service that holds the data you need to share between components.  On this service create an <s>event listener</s> event emitter something like the following:

```js
@Injectable()
export class YourGlobalService {
     public doComponentDataUpdate = new EventEmitter();
     public sharedData: any;

    constructor() {}
}
```

Now in any component where you need to get the shared data, do something like the following:

```js
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { YourGlobalService } from "./path/your-global.service";


@Component({
    selector: "some-component",
    moduleId: module.id,
    providers: [],
    templateUrl: "./some-component.html",
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

})
export class SomeComponent {
    localData: any;
    doComponentDataUpdate: any;


    constructor(yourGlobalService: YourGlobalService) {

        this.doComponentDataUpdate = yourGlobalService.doComponentDataUpdate.subscribe(() => {
             // when this is fired, your component knows to check for new data
             this.localData = yourGlobalService.sharedData;
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
          // don't forget to unsubscribe!
          this.doComponentDataUpdate.unsubscribe();
    }


}
```

Now, whenever you need to tell the components that the shared data has been updated, do the following:

> yourGlobalService.doComponentDataUpdate.emit();